# Postgresql performance question about inserting or updating many row containing binary data

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have a table A where I put many image resources with a daily frequence.

Every record of table A references another table B in which there are only fixed records.

My question is the following: better to clean all records in A and then inserting new images or
updating only the binary column of all records.

What your advice?

Comment: With testing I noticed that in terms of performance there are no difference, but as volume storage the update is really critical: up to 30% of increase disk space every time. With massive delete followed by insert no increase at all

Comment: Some keywords: MVCC, VACUUM, FILLFACTOR, HOT update. Because of multiple versions, every deleted or updated record (update is actualy a delete  + insert) leaves dead tuples behind. At some point you (or the system) have to vacuum the table. If you lower the fillfactor, there is already space created for updates and you might benefit from hot updates, updates that don't need a vacuum. These tuples get vacuumed by a microvacuum during the update.

Answer (score 1):

Advice: Do some tests and see what works best for your situation.

I would start with updates and see if I could do [HOT updates](http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/site/html/misc/hot.html). You may have to play with the FILLFACTOR to get it working. It works great for me.